# to extract the product catalog from the web in .xml

Tags: function, e-commerce

someone knows how can I extract my catalogue of products in .XML in solidus

I am trying to do it and I do not how to do it

Comment: Please provide more information. How your code looks right now or at least let people know what language do you preferred to use.

Comment: spanish, I don´t know the code